# clipping image in reactjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-redux

In, I'd like to crop an image, in a fashion like it should be view by 1048px width and 280px height in that post like below,

[image]
Example: given an image of, say, 1048px width 280px height,And next I want to crop it to have a 3:4 aspect ratio on the all post side. 
like below

[image]

The resulting image is good with 1048px and 280px but on all post is blury. As above.
I'm using reactJS with typescript and react-easy-crop library to crop image.

This is the code

```
interface Iprops{
setLargeSize?: {
        width: number;
        height: number;
    };
}

if (props.setAspect != null) {
        // Set Aspect is provided so use that
        aspectWidth = props.setAspect.width;
        aspectHeight = props.setAspect.height;
    }
    else if (props.setSize != null) {
        // Set Size is provided so use that & override any other settings
        aspectWidth = props.setSize.width;
        aspectHeight = props.setSize.height;
    }
    else if (props.setLargeSize != null){
        aspectWidth = props.setLargeSize.width;
        aspectHeight = props.setLargeSize.height;
    }

Private load() {
    aspectWidth: this.props.setSize != null || this.props.setAspect || this.props.setLargeSize != null ? this.state.aspectWidth : aspect.width,
    aspectHeight: this.props.setSize != null || this.props.setAspect || this.props.setLargeSize != null ? this.state.aspectHeight : aspect.height 
};
```

Please help me with setting proper image and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use svg concept here.. If you render your image through svg tags. Then you can set the height and width dynamically/manually.

```
<svg width="10" height="10">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

It's just an example. You can use your images like this.